# Bootstrap: Force columns to stack up vertically on mobile (responsive design)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class='carousel'>
    <div class='data-ng-repeat='{{ repeat }}'{% endif %}>
        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3 vdivide valign-wrap' data-ng-repeat='i in items'>
          <div class='valign'>
            <p class='body'>
              <span> {$ i.statistic $} </span>
              <span> {$ i.text $} </span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

With the following css:

```
.vdivide:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(196, 187, 159, 0.63);
}
.carousel {
   height: 300px;
}
```

I thus have 4 columns with a bar to separate them.
I would like them to stack up nicely when I do switch to a mobile screen. 
Any idea how could I do that using bootstrap ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Stack up nicely" because the col-xs-12 should have them on top of each other on mobile. Maybe make a fiddle so it's a bit more clear?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything other than use the correct column class names. Look at [the examples provided](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/):

> The Bootstrap 3 grid system has four tiers of classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops). You can use nearly any combination of these classes to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.
>
> Each tier of classes scales up, meaning if you plan on setting the same widths for xs and sm, you only need to specify xs.

So, for 4 columns on desktop (stacked everywhere else) just use `.col-md-3` on your repeating `div`, getting rid of `.col-xs-12.col-sm-3`.

*Note*: I really recommend against adding your own presentational CSS classes to your columns. Keep the grid completely separate and add extra markup within to achieve the same thing: you will make life much simpler for yourself going forwards.